# Stored Procedure Inserting Last Record Twice, Loop problems?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Author: Stevie G
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'Test'
BEGIN  
    DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE Ttp INT;
    DECLARE Ttpname TEXT;

    DECLARE tmp CURSOR FOR 
                       SELECT tp_id, tp_name FROM tp;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;

    OPEN tmp;

    REPEAT FETCH tmp INTO Ttp, Ttpname;

    #INITIALISE ALL INSERT VALUES TO 0 FIRST
    SET @tp = 0;
    SET @tpname = '';

    SET @tp = Ttp;
    SET @tpname = Ttpname;

    #insert into entities
    INSERT INTO entity (name) VALUES (Ttpname);

    UNTIL done END REPEAT;
    CLOSE tmp; 
END
```

The last record is duplcicating, is inserted twice when I run the procedure. Must be an issue with the Loop and condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Change**:

```
REPEAT 
    FETCH tmp INTO Ttp, Ttpname;

    #INITIALISE ALL INSERT VALUES TO 0 FIRST
    SET @tp = 0;
    SET @tpname = '';

    SET @tp = Ttp;
    SET @tpname = Ttpname;

    #insert into entities
    INSERT INTO entity (name) VALUES (Ttpname);

UNTIL done END REPEAT;
```

**To**:

```
REPEAT 
    FETCH tmp INTO Ttp, Ttpname;

    IF ( ! done ) THEN
        -- INITIALISE ALL INSERT VALUES TO 0 FIRST
        SET @tp = 0;
        SET @tpname = '';

        SET @tp = Ttp;
        SET @tpname = Ttpname;

        -- insert into entities
        INSERT INTO entity (name) VALUES (Ttpname);
    END IF;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
```

**OR**:

```
FETCH tmp INTO Ttp, Ttpname;
REPEAT 
    #INITIALISE ALL INSERT VALUES TO 0 FIRST
    SET @tp = 0;
    SET @tpname = '';

    SET @tp = Ttp;
    SET @tpname = Ttpname;

    #insert into entities
    INSERT INTO entity (name) VALUES (Ttpname);

    FETCH tmp INTO Ttp, Ttpname;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
```

It is because:

> *If you FETCH past the last row in the result set, the values of the target fields or variables are indeterminate and the `NOTFOUND` attribute returns `TRUE`.*

**Refer to**: (This is on Oracle cursors, but applicable to others as well):

- [***Oracle: Fetch Statement***](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems020.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. One thing I noted was that: Instead of the `0 row(s) returned` I got a `0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s) 1329: No data - zero rows fetched, selected or processed`.

Comment: I think you used the solution under the `OR`. Better go with solution under `To`.